# maven: Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized

Tags: java, android, maven

I want to use swagger android client, So i am deploying maven after installing it using my android studio terminal.(I am using windows)
While deploying maven to my android studio (using mvn -Drat.skip=true deploy
) I get the following error:-

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project maven: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact or
g.apache.maven:maven:pom:3.5.0 from/to apache.releases.https (https://repository.apache.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2): Failed to transfer file: https://repository.apache.o
rg/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven/3.5.0/maven-3.5.0.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
```

Comment: You need to configure your maven to authenticate to apache's repository. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html

Comment: It's still not working. Can you show me the exact way of how to do it.